# Label in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath live text update

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is there any way I can update label (let's say every 60 sec) in method cellForRowAtIndexPath using NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval?

I mean I can create a function to act as selector for the method, but I can't pass there my object:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    guard let object = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CustomObject else {return cell}
    ...}
```

Is there possible any other way I update my computed label value every (as said) 60 sec inside cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do it inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Setup your timer and inside the handler function your call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` passing in whatever row(s) you wish to reload.

This will result in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` being called for those rows.